# Branch elements not visible after relocation

Tags: clearcase

I relocated certain elements from one VOB to another VOB.
During the relocation my view was set to default config spec.

element * CHECKEDOUT
element * main\LATEST

some of the elements were branched under another branch. Below is the config spec we use for the other branch.

element * CHECKEDOUT
element * .../rel_euchanges_ban_dev/LATEST
element * WPX0445_ANL_EXIT_EUCHGS_1.0_BL.ANL_28012014 -mkbranch
rel_euchanges_ban_dev
element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch rel_euchanges_ban_dev

After relocation when we set the config spec for rel_euchanges_ban_dev branch, we are not able to properly see the elements under this branch. 
Example: This is how it looks in the source VOB, for two folders which are under the branch rel_euchanges_ban_dev. There seems to be a symbolic link to the destination VOB.
[image]

But at the destination VOB. This is how it looks.
 [image]

When the config spec is set to default, AnalysisAndDesign and Requirements folder are present only in destination VOB as expected after relocation.

Why could it be that when config spec is set for rel_euchanges_ban_dev branch, we are seeing symbolic links? Wherein ideally the folders should be available at the source VOB but not symbolic links to destination VOB.

Why could this be happening? I tried labeling corresponding folders at the destination VOB with baseline label of the sub branch. But nothing seems to work :-/

Further, the version tree at the destination VOB looks like this.
View is set to rel_euchanges_ban_dev branch.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What could happen is the new config spec isn't configured to show new elements (those in /main/0 or .../branch rel_euchanges_ban_dev/0

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * .../rel_euchanges_ban_dev/LATEST
element * WPX0445_ANL_EXIT_EUCHGS_1.0_BL.ANL_28012014 -mkbranch
rel_euchanges_ban_dev
element * /main/0 -mkbranch rel_euchanges_ban_dev <===
element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch rel_euchanges_ban_dev
```

The additional line makes sure a new element added to source control immediately in the new branch.

The [relocate man page](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.books.cc_admin.doc/vob-relo-mv.htm) mentions:

> Use a view whose config spec selects the branch (typically `main`) on which the move is to occur.
>
> The view in which you run relocate must be able to check out elements in both the source and target VOBs, so its config spec must include a `CHECKEDOUT` rule.
> After you run relocate, you may need to use this view (or a view with the same config spec) to clean up, as described in [Problems with existing views after relocating elements](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.books.cc_admin.doc/troubleshooting.htm).

So the config spec above might have been better suited for the "working view" used by the relocate.

Comment: Hi I have added the version tree at the destination VOB. I added the new line as suggested by you, but no luck. 
rel_euchanges_ban_dev is branching out from version 2 of the VOB, where as we had applied the baseline labels at the latest version of the VOB.

Comment: @user3437212 then you need to compare the version tree of each element in the path of the missing elements: the vob, the vob/firstFolder, ... And see what the difference is.

Comment: @user3437212 did you use the config spec I mention in my answer for the relocate itself, or just to consult the data in the destination vob?

Comment: I had used default config spec during relocate element * CHECKEDOUT element * main/LATEST

used the config spec that u mentioned just to check the data available.

Comment: @user3437212 my point is: using the default config spec while expecting the branch to be properly relocating might not work. Using the config spec I mention might more adequately relocate the branch you want.